# Embedding presentation slides on GitHub wiki pages

Tags: github, slideshow, wiki

I am working on the open source project, uploaded on GitHub pages. I am writing its wiki pages on GitHub. I want to link the presentation slides uploaded on slideshare.net, related to this open source project.

Can you please advice me - how can I link my presentation slides on slideshare.net with GitHub wiki pages? I want to show a first slide (included title, date, author information) of [PPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_PowerPoint) on GitHub wiki pages.

I am open to move my presentation slides on a site other than slideshare.net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embedding a slideshare presentation involves `<iframe>`, as mentioned in [slideshare FAQ](http://help.slideshare.com/entries/438663-Can-I-embed-a-SlideShare-on-my-blog-without-the-related-content-suggestions-showing-up-at-the-end-), and that is not supported in a wiki page.

You can see all the markdown supported syntax in "[Markdown-Cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet)", and that page ends up with an "integration" of a YouTube video: it is actually a picture, embedded in a classic html link.

This could be the easiest solution for you: a picture of the first slide in an html link referencing the actual slideshare page.
But that would mean leaving your wiki page for the slideshare one.

Comment: Can I directly upload my slides on GitHub?

Comment: @user3582228 What would be the format of those slides? PDF? Mardown? HTML?

Comment: Actually I make them in beamer latex . I wonder if I can upload them as latex files or even pdf.

Comment: @user3582228 https://stackoverflow.com/q/35498525/6309: there is some support for Latex on GitHub, at least.