# How to display math in an Rmd file on Github

Tags: rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I created a technical report in .rmd in RStudio with much math expression. With knit to html, it worked very well. As html file cannot rendered well on GitHub repository, I changed my .rmd output to github_document (.md) file. However, when I upload the file onto GitHub, I found formulas cannot be shown correctly. They are in the latex script format.

I was wondering which is a valid strategy to upload a rendered .rmd file (in RStudio) into a GitHub repository? (Not GitHub Pages).

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without activating GitHub Pages. HTML files have to be provided by a web server to be rendered. Without GitHub Pages, your readers have to download the HTML file and open it with a browser.

Comment: did you find something that worked for you? Can you link us to an gist example please?

Comment: I found that ![https://alexanderrodin.com/github-latex-markdown/](https://alexanderrodin.com/github-latex-markdown/) worked well. I couldn't get codecogs.com to work.

Answer (score 12):

Pandoc supports converting maths in Markdown files for displaying on GitHub via the `--webtex` parameter. Just add the necessary argument to your Rmd preamble and RMarkdown will pass the parameter on to Pandoc:

```
---
title: "My Title"
output:
  github_document:
    pandoc_args: --webtex
---

# R Markdown Document

Maths expression embedded in GitHub Markdown:

$$
E = \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}
$$

with some more inline Latex $\gamma$, $\lambda$, $\theta$
```

When the document is rendered, the intermediate Latex chunks are rendered to https://latex.codecogs.com/ and embedded in your document automatically.

This feature was added in Pandoc 2.0.4 so make sure your version is recent enough.

Since the output is just embedded web links, the output displays here on SO as well as any other markdown-supported site:

---

## My Title

## R Markdown Document

Maths expression embedded in GitHub Markdown:

[image: E = \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}]

with some more inline Latex
[image: \gamma],
[image: \lambda],
[image: \theta]

Comment: Do you know how to support ```$$
\begin{alignat}{2}
Ax &= y \\
A^{-1}Ax &= A^{-1}y \\
x &= A^{-1}y \\
\end{alignat}
$$```

Comment: Sorry this answer is not detailed enough. How do you make latex be displayed step by step? I copy paste what you have at the top in my Markdown and then what? Github is not displaying it at all...please provide step by step explanation, right now your answer is useless.