# Using GitHub LaTeX Markdown to color header text with specific colors

Tags: github, markdown, mathjax

How can I tweak this mathjax block:

```
 ${\textrm{\color{cyan}pf\color{darkorange}UI\ \ \color{aquamarine} Zen}}$
```

To have it rendered like this in the header of my GitHub Markdown file (I think the font being used by GitHub is "Segoe UI" at least in Windows/Firefox)?

```
 # <span style="color: cyan">pf</span><span style="color: orange">UI</span></span> <span style="color: aquamarine; font-size: 44px;">Zen</span>
```

[image: sample]

As a last resort, I'd also be open to solutions involving third party websites' facilities like latex.codecogs.com/svg.latex (per https://stackoverflow.com/a/45603559/863651).

Comment: GFM does not support this but you could use codecogs `https://latex.codecogs.com` . They have an editor that's pretty easy to use as well `https://editor.codecogs.com/`

Comment: This is a quick rough example `https://latex.codecogs.com/png.image?\inline&space;\LARGE&space;\dpi{300}\bg{black}\mathbf{{\color{Cyan}pf}{\color{Orange}UI}\;{\color{Cyan}Zen}}`

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan appreciate the tip - can you turn this into an answer so that I can accept it if nothing better crops up?

Comment: Yeah definitely

Comment: Does the header have to be written in some form of latex? This might be a whole lot easier with HTML and CSS, as I am sure you already know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, GFM does not support this but you could use codecogs. They have an editor that's pretty easy to use as well.

**Editor:**

`editor.codecogs.com`

**Rough Example URL:**

`https://latex.codecogs.com/png.image?\inline&space;\huge&space;\dpi{300}\bg{black}\texttt{{\color{Cyan}pf}{\color{Orange}UI}\;{\color{Green}Zen}}`

**Rough Example Preview:**

[image]

Comment: Complete markdown using url-encoding + improved font with custom sizes (a thing of beauty really!): \[pfUI Zen\](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.latex?%5Cfn_jvn%20%5Chuge%20%5Ctextup%7B%5CLARGE%5Ctextbf%7B%7B%5Ccolor%7BCyan%7Dpf%7D%7B%5Ccolor%7BOrange%7DUI%7D%5C%20%5Chuge%7B%5Ccolor%7BEmerald%7DZen%7D%7D%7D) without full url-encoding it is: https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.latex?\fn_jvn%20\huge%20\textup{\LARGE\textbf{{\color{Cyan}pf}{\color{Orange}UI}\%20\huge{\color{Emerald}Zen}}}

Comment: Nice call on the font sizes. I like that a lot